# Getting error MODULE_ADDRESS_DOES_NOT_MATCH_SENDER when publishing Move (language) module

Tags: blockchain, move-lang, aptos

I have published a module. It has a function which publishes another module. When I try to call this function the transaction commits with error `MODULE_ADDRESS_DOES_NOT_MATCH_SENDER`.

My code uses `account::create_resource_account` to create the future module owner account and Aptos framework's `aptos_framework::code::publish_package_txn(owner: &signer, metadata_serialized: vector<u8>, code: vector<vector<u8>>)` to publish the module.

I retreive the metadata and code by running these commands:
`hexdump -ve '1/1 "%02x"' ./mymodue/build/mymodue/package-metadata.bcs` and
`hexdump -ve '1/1 "%02x"' ./mymodue/build/mymodule/bytecode_modules/mymodulesource.mv`

[Here](https://github.com/move-language/move/blob/main/language/documentation/spec/vm.md#publishing) It is said that the VM does this, when a module is published:

- Check that the module address and the sender address are the same: This check verifies that the publisher is the account that will eventually hold the module. If the two addresses do not match, an error with `StatusCode::MODULE_ADDRESS_DOES_NOT_MATCH_SENDER` is returned.

Comment: I got the same `MODULE_ADDRESS_DOES_NOT_MATCH_SENDER` error when pass the Uint8Array arguments like below:
`const metadata = new HexString(packageMetadata.toString("hex")).toUint8Array(); const code = new HexString(moduleData.toString("hex")).toUint8Array();`
But if I pass the string as the arguments, I got the error: Move abort in `0x1::util: 0x10001`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you check Move.toml to make sure the named address where the module is deployed at matches that of the resource account you created?

Comment: Thank you! It turns out the `account::create_resource_account` returns the same account for the same parameters (I thought it randomly generates). Needed to run the function once (in tests) and put the created account in Move.toml